How to add StatusBar Class and Use Grid Column as Border
I am new to learning tkinter and I am trying to make a simple tkinter GUI to run EXIFTool.
problem 1) When I uncomment StatusBar I get the following error; cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack. What is the best way to format my code to prevent this problem.
problem 2) How can I keep column 0 from collapsing so it acts as a border?
#!/usr/bin/python3

import getpass
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image  
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import filedialog



class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        
        # configure the grid
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=4)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=2)
        self.columnconfigure(3, weight=2)
        self.columnconfigure(4, weight=2)
        self.columnconfigure(5, weight=4)

        self.createwidgets()
    
    def createwidgets(self):

        ### FILE
        self.entry1_var = tk.StringVar()
        #self.entry1_var.set('')
        self.entry1=tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry1_var, justify='center')
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=tk.EW, padx=0, pady=40, ipady=10 )

        ##--------------------------------------------------##

        ### SELECT BUTTON
        self.button1=tk.Button(self, text='FILE', bg="#873600", bd=4, relief="raised")
        #self.button1['command'] = self.openfile
        self.button1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=30)
        
        ### CLEAN BUTTON
        self.button2=tk.Button(self, text='INFO', bg="#873600", bd=4, relief="raised")
        #self.button2['command'] = self.exif_info
        self.button2.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=30)
        
        ### VIEW EXIF DATA
        self.button3=tk.Button(self, text='EXIF', bg="#873600", bd=4, relief="raised")
        #self.button3['command'] = self.exif_clean
        self.button3.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=30)

        ### EXIT
        self.button4=tk.Button(self, text='EXIT', bg="#873600", bd=4, relief="raised")
        #self.button4['command'] = container.exit
        self.button4.grid(column=4, row=1, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=30)

        ##--------------------------------------------------##

        ### EXIF INFO
        self.text1=tk.Text(self, height=12)
        self.text1.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=4, padx=0, pady=40, ipady=10)
        
        
        self.grid()
    
#####################################################################################

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 

        bg_colour = "#4C4E52" 

        self.geometry("1400x870") # air
        #self.configure(bg=bg_colour)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.title('EXIF CLEANER v1')

    def exit(self):
        self.destroy()

    
class StatusBar(tk.Frame):   
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        time_date = datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S %p on %A, %B the %dth, %Y')
        
        self.variable=tk.StringVar()
        self.variable.set(time_date)     
        
        self.statusbar=tk.Label(self, bd=0, relief="solid", height="2", width="100", 
            textvariable=self.variable, foreground="red", background='#2f2f2f', font=('helvetica',8))                       
        
        self.statusbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.pack(fill="x", side="bottom", ipady=0, padx=0, pady=0)


        #self.parent1 = tk.Frame()
        #self.parent1.pack(side=tk.TOP)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    #StatusBar(app)
    MainFrame(app)
    app.mainloop()


You cannot mix .grid() and .pack() inside same container.  You have used .grid() on instance of MainFrame and .pack() on instance of StatusBar which both are children of app, i.e. inside same container.


How to add StatusBar Class and Use Grid Column as Border

I get the following error; cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack


The problem can fixed:
On line 65, change this:
self.grid()

to:
self.pack()

On line 106, comment in StatusBar(app)
Screenshot:

